# Cannot render the class component on onClick (ReactJS)

Tags: reactjs, react-props, react-state

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import { Card, CardImg, CardImgOverlay, CardText, CardBody,CardTitle } from 'reactstrap';
import DishDetail from './DishdetailComponent';

class Menu extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            selectedDish: null
        }

    }

    onDishSelect(dish) {
        this.setState({ selectedDish: dish});
    }

    

    render() {
        const menu = this.props.dishes.map((dish) => {
            return (
              <div  className="col-12 col-md-5 m-1">
                <Card key={dish.id}
                  onClick={() => this.onDishSelect(dish)}>
                  <CardImg width="100%" src={dish.image} alt={dish.name} />
                  <CardImgOverlay>
                      <CardTitle>{dish.name}</CardTitle>
                  </CardImgOverlay>
                </Card>
              </div>
            );
        });

        return (
            <div className="container">
                <div className="row">
                    {menu}
                </div>
                <DishDetail dish={this.state.selectedDish} />
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Menu;
```

> This is the main menu section where all the dishes from data are displayed in cardView. Its purpose is that if one of the dishes are to be clicked, the detail of the dishes alongside the comments are to be displayed side by side below all dishes.

```
/* 
Replace the card showing the selected dish in MenuComponent's view with the DishdetailComponent, and make sure to pass the selected dish information as props to the DishdetailComponent.

Create a new DishDetail class in a file named DishdetailComponent.js in the components folder

Export the DishDetail class from this file so that it can be imported in MenuComponent.js and used to construct the view of the selected dish.

Return a <div> from the render() function. This <div> should use the Bootstrap row class to position the content within the <div>. This div will display both the details of the dish in a Card and the list of comments side-by-side for medium to extra large screens, but will stack them for xs and sm screens.

The card should be enclosed inside a <div> appropriate Bootstrap column classes so that it occupies the entire 12 columns for the xs and sm screen sizes, and 5 columns for md screens and above. Also apply a class of m-1 to this div.

The comments should be enclosed in a <div> to which you apply appropriate column classes so that it occupies the entire 12 columns for the xs and sm screen sizes, and 5 columns for md screens and above. Also apply a class of m-1 to this div.

If the dish is null then you should return an empty <div>
*/
 import React, {Component} from 'react';
 import { Card, CardImg, CardText, CardBody,CardTitle } from 'reactstrap';

 export default class DishDetail extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

    }
/* 
Implement a function named renderDish() that takes the dish as a parameter and returns the JSX code 
for laying out the details of the dish in a reactstrap Card. You have already seen this as part of the 
MenuComponent class in the exercise earlier.

Display the name of the dish as the Card title, and the description as the Card text.
*/
    renderDish(dish) {
        if (dish != null)
            return(
                <div className="col-12 col-md-5 m-1">
                    <Card>
                        <CardImg top src={dish.image} alt={dish.name} />
                        <CardBody>
                            <CardTitle>{dish.name}</CardTitle>
                            <CardText>{dish.description}</CardText>
                        </CardBody>
                    </Card>
                </div>
                
            );
        else
            return(
                <div></div>
            );
    }

/* 
Implement a function named renderComments() that takes the comments array as a parameter and lays out each comment 
as shown in the image below. You should use the Bootstrap list-unstyled class on the list.

Each comment should be displayed on two lines, the first one showing the comment, and the second line showing 
the comment author's name and the date.

The comments should contain a <h4> header with the word "Comments".

Remember to enclose the header and comments inside a <div> before returning the JSX code. Otherwise React will 
not do the layout correctly.

If the comments are null, then you should return an empty <div>.
*/

    renderComments(comments) {
        if (commments != null) {
            const commentList = comments.map((ment) => {
                return (

                    <li key={ment.id}>
                        <p>{ment.comment}</p>
                        <p>--{ment.author} , {ment.date}</p>
                    </li>
                    
                );
            });

            return (

                <div className="col-12 col-md-5 m-1">
                    <h4>Comments</h4>
                    <ul className="list-unstyled">
                        {commentList}
                    </ul>
                </div>
            );
                
        }

    }

    render() {

        if(this.props.dish != null) {
            return (
                <div className="row">
                    {this.renderDish(this.props.dish)}
                    {this.renderComments(this.props.dish.comments)}
                </div>                   
            );
        }

        else {
            return <div></div>
        }
   
    }


 }
```

> The above file is for DishDetailComponent where it renders comments and dish detail info after being clicked. The file below is'Dishes' data file.

```
export const DISHES =
    [
        {
        id: 0,
        name:'Uthappizza',
        image: 'assets/images/uthappizza.png',
        category: 'mains',
        label:'Hot',
        price:'4.99',
        description:'A unique combination of Indian Uthappam (pancake) and Italian pizza, topped with Cerignola olives, ripe vine cherry tomatoes, Vidalia onion, Guntur chillies and Buffalo Paneer.',
        comments: [
            {
            id: 0,
            rating: 5,
            comment: "Imagine all the eatables, living in conFusion!",
            author: "John Lemon",
            date: "2012-10-16T17:57:28.556094Z"
            },
            {
            id: 1,
            rating: 4,
            comment: "Sends anyone to heaven, I wish I could get my mother-in-law to eat it!",
            author: "Paul McVites",
            date: "2014-09-05T17:57:28.556094Z"
            },
            {
            id: 2,
            rating: 3,
            comment: "Eat it, just eat it!",
            author: "Michael Jaikishan",
            date: "2015-02-13T17:57:28.556094Z"
            },
            {
            id: 3,
            rating: 4,
            comment: "Ultimate, Reaching for the stars!",
            author: "Ringo Starry",
            date: "2013-12-02T17:57:28.556094Z"
            },
            {
            id: 4,
            rating: 2,
            comment: "It's your birthday, we're gonna party!",
            author: "25 Cent",
            date: "2011-12-02T17:57:28.556094Z"
            }
        ]                        },
        {
        id: 1,
        name:'Zucchipakoda',
        image: 'assets/images/zucchipakoda.png',
        category: 'appetizer',
        label:'',
        price:'1.99',
        description:'Deep fried Zucchini coated with mildly spiced Chickpea flour batter accompanied with a sweet-tangy tamarind sauce',
        comments: [
            {
            id: 0,
            rating: 5,
            comment: "Imagine all the eatables, living in conFusion!",
            author: "John Lemon",
            date: "2012-10-16T17:57:28.556094Z"
            },
            {
            id: 1,
            rating: 4,
            comment: "Sends anyone to heaven, I wish I could get my mother-in-law to eat it!",
            author: "Paul McVites",
            date: "2014-09-05T17:57:28.556094Z"
            },
            {
            id: 2,
            rating: 3,
            comment: "Eat it, just eat it!",
            author: "Michael Jaikishan",
            date: "2015-02-13T17:57:28.556094Z"
            },
            {
            id: 3,
            rating: 4,
            comment: "Ultimate, Reaching for the stars!",
            author: "Ringo Starry",
            date: "2013-12-02T17:57:28.556094Z"
            },
            {
            id: 4,
            rating: 2,
            comment: "It's your birthday, we're gonna party!",
            author: "25 Cent",
            date: "2011-12-02T17:57:28.556094Z"
            }
        ]
        },
        {
        id: 2,
        name:'Vadonut',
        image: 'assets/images/vadonut.png',
        category: 'appetizer',
        label:'New',
        price:'1.99',
        description:'A quintessential ConFusion experience, is it a vada or is it a donut?',
        comments: [
            {
            id: 0,
            rating: 5,
            comment: "Imagine all the eatables, living in conFusion!",
            author: "John Lemon",
            date: "2012-10-16T17:57:28.556094Z"
            },
            {
            id: 1,
            rating: 4,
            comment: "Sends anyone to heaven, I wish I could get my mother-in-law to eat it!",
            author: "Paul McVites",
            date: "2014-09-05T17:57:28.556094Z"
            },
            {
            id: 2,
            rating: 3,
            comment: "Eat it, just eat it!",
            author: "Michael Jaikishan",
            date: "2015-02-13T17:57:28.556094Z"
            },
            {
            id: 3,
            rating: 4,
            comment: "Ultimate, Reaching for the stars!",
            author: "Ringo Starry",
            date: "2013-12-02T17:57:28.556094Z"
            },
            {
            id: 4,
            rating: 2,
            comment: "It's your birthday, we're gonna party!",
            author: "25 Cent",
            date: "2011-12-02T17:57:28.556094Z"
            }
        ]
        },
        {
        id: 3,
        name:'ElaiCheese Cake',
        image: 'assets/images/elaicheesecake.png',
        category: 'dessert',
        label:'',
        price:'2.99',
        description:'A delectable, semi-sweet New York Style Cheese Cake, with Graham cracker crust and spiced with Indian cardamoms',
        comments: [
            {
            id: 0,
            rating: 5,
            comment: "Imagine all the eatables, living in conFusion!",
            author: "John Lemon",
            date: "2012-10-16T17:57:28.556094Z"
            },
            {
            id: 1,
            rating: 4,
            comment: "Sends anyone to heaven, I wish I could get my mother-in-law to eat it!",
            author: "Paul McVites",
            date: "2014-09-05T17:57:28.556094Z"
            },
            {
            id: 2,
            rating: 3,
            comment: "Eat it, just eat it!",
            author: "Michael Jaikishan",
            date: "2015-02-13T17:57:28.556094Z"
            },
            {
            id: 3,
            rating: 4,
            comment: "Ultimate, Reaching for the stars!",
            author: "Ringo Starry",
            date: "2013-12-02T17:57:28.556094Z"
            },
            {
            id: 4,
            rating: 2,
            comment: "It's your birthday, we're gonna party!",
            author: "25 Cent",
            date: "2011-12-02T17:57:28.556094Z"
            }
        ]
        }
    ];
```

[image: Before clicking each Card, there were no errors on the console.]

[image: However, after I clicked it, the whole cardView disappeared, leaving only blank screens with "comment is not defined" errors on the console.]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was in your renderComments function. The argument name is **comments**, But in the if check you we're using **commments** an extra m in the comment.

**Issue**

```
renderComments(comments) {
        if (commments != null) {
            const commentList = comments.map((ment) => {
                return (

                    <li key={ment.id}>
                        <p>{ment.comment}</p>
                        <p>--{ment.author} , {ment.date}</p>
                    </li>
                    
                );
            });

            return (

                <div className="col-12 col-md-5 m-1">
                    <h4>Comments</h4>
                    <ul className="list-unstyled">
                        {commentList}
                    </ul>
                </div>
            );
                
        }

    }
```

**Solution:**

```
renderComments(comments) {
            if (comments!= null) {
                const commentList = comments.map((ment) => {
                    return (
    
                        <li key={ment.id}>
                            <p>{ment.comment}</p>
                            <p>--{ment.author} , {ment.date}</p>
                        </li>
                        
                    );
                });
    
                return (
    
                    <div className="col-12 col-md-5 m-1">
                        <h4>Comments</h4>
                        <ul className="list-unstyled">
                            {commentList}
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                );
                    
            }
    
        }
```

Comment: Oh right, thank you! I've checking on it for awhile

Comment: lol, good catch :)